# Unexpected import behavior, treating integers and lists differently

Tags: python, list, module, import, integer

I have a problem with my program and I was able to reproduce this unexpected (at least unexpected to me) behavior in a small scale so now I'm certain it is not another bug.

Lets say I have 3 python modules: `one`, `two` and `three`.

In `three` we have:

```
var = 0
list = []
```

So there we have a integer that is equal to zero and and empty list.

In `two` we have:

```
from three import var, list

def funct():
    print var*2
    print list
    return
```

So we import `var` and `list` and simply define a function that will print both and return.

Instead of calling `funct()` in `two` I called it in `one`, but not before doing some "operations" to them.

```
from three import var, list
from two import funct

if 2 < 4:
    var += 1
    list.append("x")

print funct()
```

So here comes my question.

I never expected this result:

```
0
['x']
None
```

How come the `x` was added to the list with the `append()` and 1 **was NOT** added to `var`, to be clear. I was expecting:

```
2
['x']
None
```

If find it very strange that they receive different treatments under the same circumstances.

- Am I missing something here?
- Am I doing something wrong with the imports?

If not:

- Why does it behave like this?
- How should this problem be solved / approached?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be re-binding names like ‘list’, otherwise you lose access to the built-in objects by those names.

Comment: I've answered this below, and went through discovering it myself, please view my answer again. You should import "three" and use three.var += 1 to make it happen. Don't import the "var"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "fix" your program, you would have to add "global var", as in:

```
if 2 < 4:
     global var
     var += 1
     list.append("x")
```

But this is illegal according to http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#global:

> Names listed in a global statement must not be defined as formal parameters or in a for loop control target, class definition, function definition, or import statement.

Then again, following the link above:

> CPython implementation detail: The current implementation does not enforce the latter two restrictions, but programs should not abuse this freedom, as future implementations may enforce them or silently change the meaning of the program.

Edit:

The solution is to change:

```
from three import var, list
```

to:

```
from three import list
import three
```

then don't use global namespace, but specify explicitly the namespace of three (you imported the symbol)

code:

```
three.var += 1
```

Make sure two.py and one.py are changed accordingly in their import/from statements

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules

> Each module has its own private symbol table, which is used as the global symbol table by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the author of a module can use global variables in the module without worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables. On the other hand, if you know what you are doing you can touch a module’s global variables with the same notation used to refer to its functions, modname.itemname.

Comment: Hmm thanks for giving me a choice but I don't really like it, it this is the only direct solution, maybe I should try a whole different approach...

Comment: @Trufa: The whole idea of importing objects from other modules and then "updating" them by bashing on them directly instead of using methods is a really big code smell IMO, whether they are mutable or not.

Comment: @JohnMachin: Thank for the feedback, but I'm having some trouble figuring out what should be done instead...

Comment: +1 and accepted answer, this problem actually started when I went from `three.var` to `var` (now that you say). I hadn't noticed it was exactly there where the problem started and thought this had nothing to do, I will read more on this now and maybe post another question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with import, and everything to do with the different types involved.

`list` is a mutable type. `list.append` modifies the object in place, and returns `None`.

`int` is an immutable type. Its `+=` operator returns a new object.

Learn more about mutable and immutable types at the [Python documentation of its data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying, but, is this approach intrinsically wrong or should I try to solve this by trying to use a list in both cases?

Comment: You should ask a new question, which explicitly states the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'll edit my question, and add more information I think rather that a new question, I'm trying out many possibilities before I do so because the whole code is too long to just paste and ask for advice :)

Answer (score -1):

Importing a name copies the reference the name contains to your module. In your code, the integer gets rebound, but the list gets mutated. Since the list reference never changes, the original object is mutated. Hence different integer, same list.

Comment: No, the import in both cases gets a new binding to the object. Import has nothing to do with the confusion Trufa is experiencing.

Comment: But it's still the same object.

Comment: Abrams: Thanks for your answer, but I'm having some trouble following your line of though. And mainly I'm at a loss in how a more appropriate approach would look like given this situation. Thanks!!

Comment: There is no "more appropriate approach". If you need to rebind the name in its original module, then do so.